# Geometric Without Replacement?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Is there a probability distribution corresponding to a geometric distribution without replacement? By this I mean the idea of the time until the first success, but with dependent rather than independent events?

For example, the time it takes until you draw a spade from a standard deck of $52$ cards? Or if you have $5$ red and $5$ blue marbles in an urn, the time it takes until you draw a blue marble?

Is this just the hypergeometric distribution? I am inclined to say no because the hypergeometric distribution specifies the number of samples.

Comment: Well, obviously there's a probability distribution, but it sounds like you're asking if there's a name for this class of distributions.  It's certainly *close* to the hypergeometric distribution; for instance, the probability that you draw (say) the second spade from a standard deck on the sixth draw is equal to the probability that there is one spade in the first five cards, and eleven spades in the last $46$ cards.  There's an offset by one; is that close enough?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I believe it's called the [negative hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_hypergeometric_distribution).

[Here](http://math.usask.ca/~oshaughn/103Hypergeometric.pdf) is a pdf on the matter. I quote the following:

> #### The Negative Hypergeometric Distribution
>
> Let $Y$ be a random variable counting the number of selections required required until the $k$th success is obtained when sampling without replacement from a set of $N$ objects of which $M$ have a certain attribute (i.e. success). then $Y$ is said to have a Negative Hypergeometric distribution with parameters $N$, $M$, and $k$ -- that is, $Y\sim\operatorname{NHG}(N,M,k)$ -- and, for appropriate values $y$, its probability function is 
>   $$p_Y(y)\equiv P[Y=y] = \frac{\binom{M}{k-1}\binom{N-M}{y-k}}{\binom{N}{y-1}}\times \frac{M-k+1}{N-y+1}.$$

Comment: In the wiki it states: "in the negative hypergeometric distribution, samples are drawn until r failures have been found, and the distribution describes the probability of finding k successes in such a sample"

Which is not quite like "geometric without replacements", since we want to draw until we get 1 (or k, if we want to generalize) *successes*